# UiPath cannot click Chrome inspect feature "accessibility checker"

Tags: uipath

I have to automate on button "Accessibility Checker" which will come after inspecting the web page as shown in the picture. Please suggest me how to automate this as of now I am using UiPath, but that is not working (not able to select a correct Selector).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know chrome is a bit tricky since it has a lot more background updates than other browsers. So use something like IE if you can. Other than that, you can use anchor base activity with image activities. I get accurate results with that solution on cases where I am not able to use clicks.